# Looping through a map in Solidity

Tags: arrays, for-loop, maps, solidity

I have started learning Solidity a couple weeks ago. I am still a newbie and I am stuck on something. I have tried stuct, array, maps but I do not manage to make it work.

I am trying to make a little game to learn Solidity. Each player will buy tickets, they can buy as many ticket as they want. And then, I am going to use the VRF of chainlink to select a random ticket to pick a winner. I need to map each ticketId (ticket1, ticket 2, ticket3...) with the address of the player. So, each time a new player enters the game and tells how many ticket he wants, I want to increment my array tickets by the number of tickets he bought. For instance if I have player1 who bought 3 tickets and player2 who bought 4 tickets, I would want my array to be (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) with each ticketId mapped to the address of the player.

Thanks guys for the help ;)

```
contract Test {
    mapping(uint => address payable) public myMap; // map tickets with address of players
    uint[] public ticketId; // array of ticketId purchased (1,2,3,....)

    uint arrayLength = ticketId.length;

    function set(uint _numberticket) public { // tickets to be purchased by player
        for(uint i=arrayLength+1; i<arrayLength+_numberticket+1; i++) {
            ticketId.push(i); 
            myMap[ticketId[uint(i)]]=payable(msg.sender); // linking the ticketId purchased with the address of player
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems a bit redundant, why not have a mapping of `uint[] => address` where you can store the array of `ticketIds` on the map, and externally have an array of addresses, so that way you can iterate over each address if necessary?

Comment: Thanks @MrFrenzoid for the answer! You mean, instead of having my array of ticketId, I create an array of addresses? I do not see how will I be able to have my array ticketId which increments each time a player buys 1 or several tickets.